# why fail with http post in c++?

Tags: c++, http-headers

I have code below ,but nginx give me 500.I don't know why,please help me.

and the header are here,

i can't find any error.some one ever encountered ?

```
POST http://sss.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: sss.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 241047
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://sss.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.849.0 Safari/535.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://sss.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=krje6jlnls57ejc0p4jqhkd2k7

------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"


4
------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="/home/heida/test/1152_648.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream



------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO--
```

the nginx give me the result below:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
> Server: nginx
> Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2016 12:28:23 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Content-Length: 537
> Connection: close
> ETag: "54b4def1-219"
> ```

and the code is below:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cerrno>

using namespace std;

std::string get_file_contents(const char *filename)
{
  std::FILE *fp = std::fopen(filename, "rb");
  if (fp)
  {
    std::string contents;
    std::fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    contents.resize(std::ftell(fp));
    std::rewind(fp);
    std::fread(&contents[0], 1, contents.size(), fp);
    std::fclose(fp);
    return(contents);
  }
  throw(errno);
}

int request(char* hostname, char* api,string & content)
{

    //socket
    struct hostent* host_addr = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (host_addr == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Unable to locate host"<<endl;
        return -103;
    }


    sockaddr_in sin;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)80);
    sin.sin_addr=  *((struct in_addr *)host_addr->h_addr);
    bzero(&(sin.sin_zero),8);

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        return -100;
    }


    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr) ) == -1)
    {
        cout<<"connect failed"<<endl;
        return -101;
    }



    char send_str[2048] = {0};



    strcat(send_str, "POST ");
    strcat(send_str, api);
    strcat(send_str, " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "Host: ");
    strcat(send_str, hostname);
    strcat(send_str, "\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "Connection: keep-alive\r\n");


    char content_header[100];
    sprintf(content_header,"Content-Length: %d\r\n", content.size());


    strcat(send_str, content_header);
    strcat(send_str, "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "Origin: http://yyfs.yy.com\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.849.0 Safari/535.1\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "Referer: http://yyfs.yy.com/\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8\r\n");
    strcat(send_str,"Cookie: PHPSESSID=krje6jlnls57ejc0p4jqhkd2k7\r\n");    


    strcat(send_str, "\r\n");
    strcat(send_str,"------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO\r\n");
    strcat(send_str,"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "\r\n");
    strcat(send_str, "4\r\n");
    strcat(send_str,"------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO\r\n");
    strcat(send_str,"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upfile\"; filename=\"/home/heida/test/1152_648.png\"\r\n");
    strcat(send_str,"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");

    cout<<send_str<<endl;
    if (send(sock, send_str, strlen(send_str),0) == -1)
    {
        cout<<"send failed"<<endl;
        return -101;
    }

    if (send(sock, content.c_str(), content.size(),0) == -1)
    {

       cout<<"send failed"<<endl;
       return -1;
    }
    char ends[190] = {0};
    strcat(ends, "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO--\r\n");
    cout<<ends<<endl;
    if (send(sock, ends, strlen(ends),0) == -1)
    {
      cout<<"send failed"<<endl;
      return -1;

    }



    char recv_str[4096] = {0};
    if (recv(sock, recv_str, sizeof(recv_str), 0) == -1)
    {
        cout<<"recv failed"<<endl;
        return -101;
    }


    cout<<recv_str<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::string files =  get_file_contents("1152_648.png");
    cout<<files.size()<<endl;
    request("sss.com","http://ssy.com/",files);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the server logs, what happens there? Have you tried posting using e.g. CURL or other command-line program?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg i use other tool ,it work rightly.but i can't find any wrong in my codes.

Answer (score 0):

I find the wrong place ,it is content-length.
the content-length include file size and below size

> ------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/home/heida/test/1152_648.png"
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> 塒NG
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO--

right code:

```
char endsss[190] = {0};
    strcat(endsss,"------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO\r\n");
    strcat(endsss,"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"/home/heida/test/1152_648.png\"\r\n");
    strcat(endsss,"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");

    char ends[190] = {0};
    strcat(ends, "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarybZRmyZBq9p09AotO--\r\n");

    char content_header[100];
    sprintf(content_header,"Content-Length: %d\r\n",content.size()+strlen(endsss)+strlen(ends));
```